# invalid_credentials on JWT auth laravel

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, jwt

I'm using jwt-auth for auth API with laravel and write following code.

My register API working good bug my login API return `invalid_credentials` error.
why?

laravel version: 5.4

```
public function login(Request $request) {

    $credentials = $request->only('username', 'password');

    try {
        $token = JWTAuth::attempt($credentials);
        if (!$token) {
            return response()->json(['error' => 'invalid_credentials'], 401);
        }
    } catch (JWTException $e) {
        return response()->json(['error' => 'could_not_create_token'], 400);
    }

    return response()->json(compact('token'), 200);
}

public function register(Request $request) {

    $credentials = $request->only('email', 'username', 'password', 'name');

    $validator = Validator::make($credentials, [
        'name' => 'required|max:80',
        'username' => 'required|max:80|unique:users',
        'email' => 'required|email|max:255|unique:users',
        'password' => 'required|min:6',
    ]);

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        $errors = $validator->errors();
        return response()->json(['error' => array(
            'name'     => $errors->first('name'),
            'email'    => $errors->first('email'),
            'username'    => $errors->first('username'),
            'password' => bcrypt('password'),
        )], 400);
    }

    $user = User::create([
        'name'      => $request->name,
        'email'     => $request->email,
        'username'  => $request->username,
        'password'  => $request->password,
    ]);

    $token = JWTAuth::fromUser($user);
    return response()->json(compact('token'));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `email` instead `username`. Laravel uses column `email` and JWTAuth also following this.

```
 $credentials = $request->only('email', 'password');
```

To make change username column as `username` you need to change inside `username` function in controller.

Check the example from [github JWTAuth](https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth/wiki/Creating-Tokens)

Comment: Can try to new register with ` Hash::make` I stead ` bcrypt`

Comment: update what you have current code and the view part also ?

Comment: Oh, I find a bug in my code.I'm doing bcrypt in validation and I'm nothing on user create. I corrected this and it working for me

Comment: I have posted my answer

Comment: but it goes into this code if `$validator->fails()` what if there is valid credentials ?

Answer (score 1):

I try any solution and not working and again check my code and find a bug in my code. I'm doing bcrypt in validation and nothing on user create. Corrected this and it working for me.

```
public function login(Request $request) {

    $credentials = $request->only('username', 'password');

    try {
        $token = JWTAuth::attempt($credentials);
        if (!$token) {
            return response()->json(['error' => 'invalid_credentials'], 401);
        }
    } catch (JWTException $e) {
        return response()->json(['error' => 'could_not_create_token'], 400);
    }

    return response()->json(compact('token'), 200);
}

public function register(Request $request) {

    $credentials = $request->only('email', 'username', 'password', 'name');

    $validator = Validator::make($credentials, [
        'name' => 'required|max:80',
        'username' => 'required|max:80|unique:users',
        'email' => 'required|email|max:255|unique:users',
        'password' => 'required|min:6',
    ]);

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        $errors = $validator->errors();
        return response()->json(['error' => array(
            'name'     => $errors->first('name'),
            'email'    => $errors->first('email'),
            'username'    => $errors->first('username'),
            'password' => $errors->first('password'),
        )], 400);
    }

    $user = User::create([
        'name'      => $request->name,
        'email'     => $request->email,
        'username'  => $request->username,
        'password'  => bcrypt($request->password),
    ]);

    $token = JWTAuth::fromUser($user);
    return response()->json(compact('token'));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case this error was because duplicate emails in my table :(