# How can i fix error InvalidArgumentException: Auth guard [customers] is not defined. in JWT

Tags: laravel, api, jwt

I have error when do login in api by jwt ..when  i do register its good will but in login display error

> InvalidArgumentException: Auth guard [customers] is not defined. in
>   file C:\Users\Ahmed\Desktop\project
>   web\laravel_pro\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Auth\AuthManager.php
>   on line 84

this is the **controller**

```
public function login(Request $request){
    $credentials = $request->only('email', 'password');

    if (Auth::guard('customer')->attempt($credentials))
    {
       $user= JWTAuth::guard('customer')->user(); 
       $jwt = JwtAuth::generateToken($user);

       return response()->json(compact('jwt'));

    }else{

        return response()->json(['error' => 'invalid_credentials'], 400);
    }
```

this is **the api route**

```
Route::post('login','UserController@login');
```

this is the **auth.php**

```
 'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],

        'api' => [
            'driver' => 'token',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],

        'customer'=>[
          'driver' => 'token',
          'provider'=> 'customers',
        ]

    ],

'providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\User::class,
        ],
        'customers' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Customer::class,
        ],
```

please any body help my to Solution..Thank you

Comment: Try to run `php artisan config:clear` or `php artisan config:cache`

Comment: i tried before aloes it's not working do you have another Solution

Comment: but after run php artisan config :cache  ....the error change to Call to undefined method Illuminate\Auth\TokenGuard::attempt()

Comment: Change your driver from `token` to `session` `'driver' => 'session',` After that run again `php artisan cache:clear
 php artisan config:cache`

Comment: thank you  i searched and i found the solution from token and change to session ..but now display new error invalid_credentials .....   does my code true or false  ???

Comment: Is there a mistake in my code?

Comment: Check these https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50027029/invalid-credentials-on-jwt-auth-laravel
https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth/issues/1324

Answer (score 0):

First Change your guard's `driver` from `token` to `session` and then run the below commands

```
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan config:cache
```

Comment: the error it fixed but always give my     "error": "invalid_credentials"
 when login in postman ...However i'am using >Hash::make when do register for password

Comment: @ahmedaljabli `Laravel` uses `email` field for authentication by default; have you taken steps to authenticate using username instead?

Comment: i know the Laravel uses email by default and l'am using email  l'am not using username

Comment: check this https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth/issues/341

Answer (score 0):

**First guess**: in `config/auth.php` **the driver for your desired guard should be 'jwt'** instead of 'token', because 'token' driver works against a fixed hash in the users table, as opposed to `jwt` that is volatile and doesn't query the DB to figure out the user.

**Second guess** : you're using the same controller for "internal users" ('api' guard), and "customer users" (should use 'customer' guard). This is confusing. Where are you discriminating the user type?

**Regarding the error**

> Auth guard [customers] is not defined.

Check that it's not a typo and you always address it as 'customer', since  'customer**s**' is not a guard but a provider. For example, check if the route middleware (e.g. `Route::['middleware'=>'auth:customer']`

---

**Having said that...**

I guess you installed [tymondesigns/jwt-auth](https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth), whose configuration guide points to a scenario where you replace the `api` guard to use  so, under that assumpion, make sure you've implemented the following modifications:

1. If using Laravel 5.4 or below, you would need to [follow these steps](https://jwt-auth.readthedocs.io/en/develop/laravel-installation/). On newer version they are handled for you so you can skip this step
2. As I said above, in `config/auth.php` **the driver for your desired guard should be 'jwt'** instead of 'token', because 'token' driver works against a fixed hash in the users table, as opposed to `jwt` that is volatile and doesn't query the DB to figure out the user.
3. You need to implement the `JWTSubject` interface on your `Customer` model  (just add things, don't need to touch the other methods)

   use Tymon\JWTAuth\Contracts\JWTSubject;

   class Customer extends Authenticatable implements JWTSubject
    {

   ```
   /**
    * Get the identifier that will be stored in the subject claim of the JWT.
    *
    * @return mixed
    */
   public function getJWTIdentifier()
   {
       return $this->getKey();
   }

   /**
    * Return a key value array, containing any custom claims 
    * to be added to the JWT.
    *
    * @return array
    */
   public function getJWTCustomClaims()
   { 
       // just an example here, change it to whatever you want
       return [
          'picture' => 'picture', // array values are the fieldname in the DB
          'twitter' => 'twitter_url' 
       ];
   }
   ...
   ```
4. Your controller should implement the corresponding guard in the constructor, and **whitelist the login method** since there is no JWT in the incoming headers.

   // UserController 
     public function __construct()
     {
       $this->middleware('auth:users', ['except' => ['login']]);
     }

   public function login()
     {
       $credentials = request(['email', 'password']);
       // token is returned from attempt
       if (! $token = auth()->attempt($credentials)) {
           return response()->json(['error' => 'Unauthorized'], 401);
       }
       return response()->json([
           'access_token' => $token,
           'token_type' => 'bearer',
           'expires_in' => auth()->factory()->getTTL() * 60
       ]);
     }
     ... other methods ...

I'd start by discarding the obvious:

- are you still able to login as user (api guard)? if yo do, try to change the driver to 'jwt'